# How to pass hashmap value to a function

Tags: java, hashmap

I have used elipses in my function like :

```
public static void test(int parameter1, HashMap... args) {
        System.out.print("\n" + parameter1);

}
```

Want to call this function with hashMap value directly like this : `test(2,{test1=test1, test=test})`

my desired final scenario is to pass different key-value pairs to the function and want to access them within the function.

Say `test(2,key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3 ....` and so on ). any datatype can be suggested instead of HashMap.

Comment: There is no "shortcut" syntax for creating such, although initialization blocks may be useful. (Also, you really don't want `...` like that.)

Comment: I don't know your program but maybe it worth to consider using the Map interface instead of the HashMap and also to use types (like Map<String, String>.

Comment: With HashMap... args you are actually passing HashMap[] args. I think this is not what you want. Your syntax looks like Groovy, maybe you should take a look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can use like following

```
test(2, new HashMap() {{put("test1", "test1");
                       put("test", "test");}});
```

Comment: Creating anonymous inner classes is generally not a good idea. It will compile to a separate class file and use some of the PermGen space. It might be a better idea to implement a builder pattern constructing the  HashMap with a fluent API.

Answer (score 3):

The elipses mean that you can pass in a number of HashMaps. I don't think that this is what you intend to do. 
You can just pass in the whole HashMap if that is what you want. Or you can retrieve values from the HashMap, and pass those in. But if you want the key/value pairs, then it's best to just pass in the whole HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Your function (using `String` as type):

```
private static void test(final Pair<String, String>... args) {
    for (Pair<String, String> p : args) {
        System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", p.getKey(), p.getValue());
    }
}
```

An example call:

```
test(new Pair<String, String>("test1", "test1"),
     new Pair<String, String>("test", "test")
);
```

This example's output:

```
test1=test1
test=test
```